# What is the best high performance Javascript Collections (Collection<T>)?

Tags: javascript, collections, knockout.js

The most important starting point was absence of "ADD" option. I could not recognize "splice" function! With splice attention I'm accepting the answer.

I'm planning to use knockout.js for my next project. But I need javascript equivalent of c# Collection .

-Add
-Remove
-Contains

I have two criterias for this requirement.

- Production Ready
- Good Performance

Javascript version of this

```
    public class UserResponse
    {
        public Question Question { get; set; }
        public Answer SelectedAnswer { get; set; }
    }
    public class Answer
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class Question
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Answer> Answers{ get; set; }
    }
    // User dont need to response every question
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<UserResponse> Responses{ get; set; }
        public void AddResponse(UserResponse response)
        {
            // Find if another answer for response.Question and remove it
            var res=Responses.Where(p => p.Question == response.Question).FirstOrDefault();
            if (res != null)
                Responses.Remove(res);
            // Add new response
            Responses.Add(response);
        }
    }
```

Backbone : 1 - Knockout: 0

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-add

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-remove

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-get

Comment: What kind of collection?

Comment: How exactly are Javascript arrays not enough?

Comment: They dont have Add,Remove,Contains method or where Extensions. I've written sample C# code.

Comment: Knockout's observable array has most, if not all, of what you require!

Comment: Backbone : 1 - Knockout: 0 http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-add  http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-remove http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use knockout's observable array, or the "extensions" found in the ko.utils namespace. That's usually more than enough for what I need!

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html

I would say backbone: 1 knockout: 1 (or 2 remove + removeAll, or 3 reverse, sort, shift, etc.)